# C# JsonElement to string without formatting

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json, jsonelement

I need to convert a JsonElement to string but without any carriage return, tabs or spaces.  A simple ToString() works but leaves those in:

```
data.ToString()
```

Results:

> "{\r\n        "Field1": "Value1",\r\n        "Field2": "Value2"\r\n    }"

Looking for:

> "{"Field1": "Value1","Field2":"Value2"}"

Sure I could do a simple find and replace string command.  However, there will be some fields that will contain carriage return, or tabs or spaces and I don't want to change those.

edit: cannot delete this please someone delete this as it has already been answered.

Comment: Since you don't want to disturb special characters in string literals, your best bet is probably to write your own method that processes the overall JSON string. It'll have to keep track of whether or not it's in a string literal as it traverses the JSON, but that's not hard to do.

Comment: Both of your examples are invalid json and invalid json strings too. Please post the real code if you need the real help. And use Newtonsoft.Json. In this case you will not need any convertation. Text.Json is a garbage and you always need to create an extra code for anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In .NET 6 you can use [`JsonNode.ToJsonString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode.tojsonstring?view=net-6.0#system-text-json-nodes-jsonnode-tojsonstring(system-text-json-jsonserializeroptions)) (using the System.Text.Json.Nodes namespace), but you'd need to convert from the `JsonElement` to a `JsonObject` first:

```
var jsonString = JsonObject.Create(data).ToJsonString();
```

`ToJsonString()` takes `JsonSerializerOptions` as parameter so you could specify `WriteIndented` if you wanted different behaviour, but by default it will output with `WriteIndented = false` (which is your desired format).

Could be converted to an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToJsonString(this JsonElement element, bool indent = false) 
        => element.ValueKind != JsonValueKind.Object
            ? "" 
            : JsonObject.Create(element).ToJsonString(new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = indent });
}

// usage
// non-indented
var jsonString = element.ToJsonString();
// indented
var jsonString = element.ToJsonString(true);
```